# Reflection, get DataAnnotation attributes from buddy class

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes

I need to check if property has specific attribute defined in its buddy class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]
public sealed partial class Address
{
    private sealed class Metadata
    {
        [Required]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How to check what properties has defined `Required` attribute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done using exploration of nested types:

```
public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetRequiredProperties()
{
    var nestedTypes = typeof(Address).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var nestedType = nestedTypes.First(); // It can be done for all types

    var requiredProperties =
        nestedType.GetProperties()
            .Where(property => 
                           property.IsDefined(typeof(RequiredAttribute), false));

    return requiredProperties;
}
```

Usage example:

```
[Test]
public void Example()
{
    var requiredProperties = GetRequiredProperties();
    var propertiesNames = requiredProperties.Select(property => property.Name);

    Assert.That(propertiesNames, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] { "Address1", "Zip" }));
}
```

Comment: While this works, it gives the wrong assumption about the relationship of the 'buddy' (metadata) class as it is defined via attributes. In other words, an ideal solution would inspect the root type for the `MetadataTypeAttribute` to get to the buddy type, rather than `GetNestedTypes()`. This method is NOT valid for all such metadatatype classes, unless they are nested. It will also return `RequiredAttribute`s for properties which are NOT defined in the metadata class from other classes which are also nested (if they exist)

Answer (score 0):

Although less elegant then Elisha's solution, but it works also :)

Your attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple=false)]
class RequiredAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string Name {get; set; }

    public RequiredAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public RequiredAttribute()
    {
        this.Name = "";
    }
}
```

Some class:

```
class Class1
{
    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
RequiredAttribute ra = new RequiredAttribute();

Type class1Type = c.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = class1Type.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo p in propInfoList)
{
    object[] a = p.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    foreach (object o in a)
    {
        if (o.GetType().Equals(ra.GetType()))
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(p.Name + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution usinjg `AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider`:

```
var entity = CreateAddress();
var type = entity.GetType();
var metadata = (MetadataTypeAttribute)type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
var properties = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type, metadata.MetadataClassType).GetTypeDescriptor(type).GetProperties();
bool hasAttribute = HasMetadataPropertyAttribute(properties, "Name", typeof(RequiredAttribute));

private static bool HasMetadataPropertyAttribute(PropertyDescriptorCollection properties, string name, Type attributeType)
{
    var property = properties[name];
    if ( property == null )
        return false;

    var hasAttribute = proeprty.Attributes.Cast<object>().Any(a => a.GetType() == attributeType);
    return hasAttribute;
}
```